# Azure WM, bing image search delaying to fetch search results

Tags: image, search, delay, bing

I have a simple page like google page. one input text box and a button. if user enters search keywords and hits enter, then search results getting delayed to display, meaning search results are displaying after some 3-8 seconds. Can anybody please tell me what could be the problem? Even the Youtube video search results are also having same problem.